# How to build programmatically the path for object data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a data object that looks like the shot below:

[image]

The data is coming from my Redux store, so when I want to display let's say the IP of camera_1, I can reach it the following way: `this.props.data.settings.cameras.camera_1.IP._text`

My problem is that if I want to build programmatically the path above I get an error because REACT take the path as a string. Yes I know, I'm building the path with literal strings but how to solve the problem? :-/

This is the way I'm trying to build the path:

```
const root = this.props.data.settings
// The following strings are coming from the previous page as routing params
const {page,node,item} = this.props.match.params


// The strings have the following values
page = 'cameras'
node = 'camera_1'
item = 'IP'

const fullPath = `${root}.${page}.${node}.${item}._text`
```

I appreciate your time and help!

Thanks :-)))

Comment: Try `this.props.data.settings[page][node][item]._text` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Thanks a mill @Tholle. That worked like charm!

Comment: @FernandoMartz Great! You're welcome.

Comment: @Tholle I hope I did it correctly. I'm a bit newbie for posting questions. Just in case, YES, your answer solved my problem.

Comment: @Tholle done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the final value by accessing values in the object with the variables `page`, `node`, `item` as keys:

```
const text = this.props.data.settings[page][node][item]._text;
```

If you want the path as a string, you could use [`lodash.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get):

```
const fullPath = `props.data.settings.${page}.${node}.${item}._text`;
const text = _.get(this, fullPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick replies. @Tholle answer solved the problem:

You can get the final value by accessing values in the object with the variables page, node, item as keys:

const text = this.props.data.settings[page][node][item]._text;
If you want the path as a string, you could use lodash.get:

const fullPath = `props.data.settings.${page}.${node}.${item}._text`;
const text = _.get(this, fullPath);

Comment: If an answer helped, you should consider accepting it instead of posting your own which is just a repost.